# SpeechRecognition not listening on Chromium

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, puppeteer, chromium

I'm trying to build a Javascript bot by using Puppeteer to open a https URL where I can listen for the microphone and output a transcript from the SpeechRecogniton API built in a browser, the below code seems to log something in normal Chrome, but on Chromium I get nothing despite this feature apparently being supported according to Modernizr. I've allowed microphone permissions but I get a dead console.log

```js
window.SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition

const recognition = new SpeechRecognition()
recognition.interimResults = true

recognition.addEventListener('result', e => {
  const transcript = Array.from(e.results)
    .map(result => result[0])
    .map(result => result.transcript)
    .join('')

    // I get nothing logged here in Chromium
    console.log(transcript)
})

recognition.addEventListener('end', recognition.start)

recognition.start()
```

**UPDATE**

After adding the following...

```js
recognition.addEventListener('error', function(event) { 
  console.log('Speech recognition error detected: ' + event.error);
});
```

I'm getting a `Network` error... and don't know what to do about this in Chromium?

Comment: Try adding "onstart", "onend" and "onerror" callbacks to your "recognition" object. You'll most likely see "onerror" trigger. Also, check https://caniuse.com/speech-recognition under Edge.

Comment: Yeah I've just tried this, getting a error key of `Network` within the error event in Chromium?? Any idea why?

Comment: unsure why it'd be a Network error (I think mine had type: 'not-allowed` or some such) but it's irrelevant. in the link I posted of caniuse it says speech recognition is not supported in the latest version of chromium-based edge

Answer (score 1):

Chromium no longer supports SpeechRecognition. I believe it's got something to do with Google wanting people to use their cloud services instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).